# DNS server with bind in Debian 9

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, security, bind, dig

I have a project to do for college. The project is a DNS server with client. I created the DNS server but when I want to see how it works I use the command dig myservername.

1. How can I proceed to see the authority, answer when I use the dig command?
2. How can I change the default IP address of my server?

!!! For my DNS server I used BIND
I don't know if well done the server. If you have any other tutorial for this kind of server that would be very helpful.

This is the output when I use the dig command:

```
root@debian:/home/radu# dig -x 10.0.2.30
; <<>> Dig 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> -x 10.0.2.30
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMANIN, id: 7666
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; ENDS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION :
; 30.2.0.10.in-adr.arpa.                   IN     PTR 


;; QUERY time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: WED JAN 09 15:40:33 EET 2019
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 51
```

Answer (score 0):

Q:How can i proceed to see the authority, answer when i use the dig command?

A: dig  SOA +noall +answer  ie...

> $ dig google.com SOA +noall +answer
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> google.com SOA +noall +answer
>
> ;; global options: +cmd
>
> google.com.        47  IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 295108804 900 900 1800 60

Q:  how can i change the default IP address of my server?

A:[Static IP in Debian 9](https://medium.com/@cpt_midnight/static-ip-in-debian-9-stretch-acb4e5cb7dc1)

As far as tutorials I can't be much help.  [This book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) taught me everything I know about DNS/BIND.  It's knowledge transcends OS as well.  What you will learn will carry forward between Debian, RHEL, Windows... Every OS

Comment: The `q-soa` thing looks broken. You're just looking up the name `q-soa` which doesn't make any sense.